# How to add blur effect around the circle on the map Mapbox Maplibre GL Native

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapkit, mapbox-gl, mglmapview

I have a map with a circle over the user location. Used Mapbox Maplibre GL Native. I want to add the blur around this circle, so inside circle will be no blur, but around all the map will be blured.

I've created a blur effect and added this to the map:

```
// Create a blur effect view

let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = mapView.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5 // Adjust opacity as needed
mapView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

After this added a circle over the user location:

```
// Create a new circle feature with the updated coordinates
let newCircleFeature = MGLPointFeature()
newCircleFeature.coordinate = currentLocation.coordinate

// Update the circle feature
circleFeature = newCircleFeature

// Update the shape of the circle source
if let existingSource = circleSource {
    existingSource.shape = circleFeature as? MGLShape
} else {
    // Create a new circle source and layer if it doesn't exist
    circleSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "circle-source", shape: circleFeature as? MGLShape, options: nil)
    mapView.style?.addSource(circleSource!)

    circleLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "circle-layer", source: circleSource!)
    circleLayer?.circleColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.clear) // Adjust the color as needed
    circleLayer?.circleOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0.5) // Adjust the opacity as needed
    circleLayer?.circleRadius = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 200) // Adjust the radius as needed
    circleLayer?.circleStrokeColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.black) // Adjust the radius as needed
    circleLayer?.circleStrokeWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 4)
                            
    mapView.style?.addLayer(circleLayer!)
}
```

And also if it possible to make, that when user will move, the circle will move with him and visible area inside circle too.